# How to avoid installing a gem in Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

In my Gemfile I have the following line:

```
gem "thin", :group => [:staging, :production]
```

When I run bundle install in the development it actually installs thin, which is a problem in the Widows boxes because thin depends on eventmachine which doesn't compile. Is there a way to avoid installing those gems in Windows all together?

We actually tried running running:

```
bundle install --without staging production
```

and it tried to install thin anyway.

What's the proper way to workaround this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hack would be to do:

```
gem "thin", :group => [:staging, :production], :platforms => :ruby
```

http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html#PLATFORMS-platforms-

> There are a number of Gemfile platforms:
>
> ruby
>
> C Ruby (MRI) or Rubinius, but NOT Windows

Answer (score 2):

I do this. Ugly, but effective

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM != "i386-mingw32" # if Windows
  gem "thin"
end
```